# User to be redirected to another URL after successful SSO authentication

Tags: lightning, oauth2, single-sign-on, configuration

I want the users to be redirected to another URL (visualforce tab) after successful SSO authentication. We have setup SP initiated SSO. Our Identity provider uses SAML 2.0 and as per a salesforce article, changing the Relay state parameter will suffice.

As per the release notes of winter '14 release, the relay state has been changed to "/" by default. (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008s0lIAA). So changing the default Landing tab is enough for redirecting the users to the specified tab. But it is not happening. Am I missing anything ?